# How to return 1 or -1 if number is positive or negative (including 0)?

Tags: python, math

Can I ask how to achieve this in Python:

Input:
`I = [10,-22,0]`

Output:
`O = [1,-1,-1]`

I was thinking
`O=I/abs(I)`

But how to deal with zero?

Comment: you can use a loop, iterate over every element of the list and have an `if` condition for `0`

Comment: Are you using pure python?

Comment: What do you mean "pure" python? I am using python

Comment: I mean if you want speed and you are doing numeric calculations on arrays then you should use numpy

Comment: I see. thanks for the help

Answer (score 10):

The following should do what you want:

```
>>> I = [10,-22,0]
>>> O = [1 if v > 0 else -1 for v in I]
>>> O
[1, -1, -1]
>>>
```

If you want to use `map` with a `lambda`, you can do:

```
>>> O = map(lambda v: 1 if v > 0 else -1, I)
>>> O
[1, -1, -1]
>>>
```

Comment: thank you! Is there a vectorised way to do that? I am not sure if "for loop" will slow down the calculation.

Comment: It's called a comprehension.  It should be very efficient.

Comment: I added a `lambda` version if you really don't like comprehensions.

Comment: using map  with a lambda will be by far the slower of the two.

Comment: You can't do better than @TomKarzes solution with list comprehension. Elegant, simple and fast.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do this:

```
I = [10,-22,0]
output = []

for num in I:
    if num <=0:
        output.append(-1)
    else:
        output.append(1)

print output
```